# Add contact to pushbullet with the api

Tags: c#, json, http, bad-request, pushbullet

I'm trying to add a contact to my contacts on pushbullet using the api.

I send following json data with my POST request to https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/contacts

```
{ "name": "some name", "email": "test@example.com" }
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.pushbullet.com/#contacts) this should add the contact.
Instead I get a bad request error.

When requesting my list of contacts via the api, it is always empty. I can add contacts using the Windows desktop client and via the web. However those contacts only show up on the desktop and on the web, not when using the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request works fine for me, what exactly is the request you are using and what does the bad request error say?

Contacts were recently replaced with /v2/chats, which is not documented yet, I should replace them in the docs, sorry about that!

Comment: The request does indeed work, I just found out that I forgot to set the content type to json for this request. Thank you for your help, the documentation for chats would be very helpful.

Comment: I tried a GET request on api.pushbullet.com/v2/chats, but that gives me a 403 error and following message: Insufficient authorization. Is this part of the api not accessible for developpers?

Comment: Yeah, since it's not public yet.  I fixed that just now.

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you for your help! Is it possible to add some documentation about adding chats, sending pushes via chats?

Comment: Pushes are sent the normal way (email field), I will add docs hopefully in the near future.